Are Twitter cards yet X cards (or anything else)?
This week, all Twitter URLs became X URLs (all twitter.com pages now load as x.com pages).
In updating my websites’ links to X/Twitter, I wonder whether I should yet update my websites’ <meta> elements regarding Twitter/X cards.
Should these…
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="___">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="___">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://___.___/___/___.___">
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="___">

Be changed yet to these (or to anything else)?
<meta name="x:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="x:title" content="___">
<meta name="x:description" content="___">
<meta name="x:image" content="https://___.___/___/___.___">
<meta name="x:image:alt" content="___">

The official documentation does not appear to have been updated for several years.
https://developer.x.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/abouts-cards
Thank you.

Unless someone at X announces that these have changed, they should be left as they are.  X's own source code is still full of references to Twitter.  It's a mess.
The tags themselves do not reference the old URL directly, so the URL update should not have impacted them.
Just checked a few big news sites, plus Tesla's site, and they're all still using the old cards.
The trend under Musk has been to downplay any off-site links rather than give people the opportunity to enhance them, and so I doubt they will bother updating code primarily designed to help people  promote off-site pages.  It simply doesn't seem to be the sort of thing they care about any more.  However, if they do, they will need to announce it if they want it implementing.  As bad as they are, I don't think they'd expect devs to find out about such things by trial-and-error.
